# Express fileupload mv() function override the existing file if the same name is given?

Tags: node.js, express-fileupload

This is my code:

```
  if (req.files && req.files.logo) {
    const logo = req.files.logo
    logo.mv('./static/' + logo.name)
    fields['logo'] = logo.name
  }
```

so if the file with the same name is uploaded then does the above `logo.mv` function call will override the previously uploaded file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should change the name if you want to keep the file history.